# integrate Fingerprint Scanner FS80 with Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, fingerprint

Can anyone provide me with good links to integrate fingerprint scanner with Raspberry pi. I heard that Futronic fs 80 is compatible with raspberry pi can you provide me some links for the same?

Comment: having a quick look at their [brochure](http://www.futronic-tech.com/download/FS80_brochure.pdf)(pdf link) I see this is a USB device. I see ARM9 listed in their supported drivers. I'd first start by trying to install the driver and their software because Raspberry PI 1 has an armv6 CPU and Raspberry PI 2 has an armv7 CPU. If drivers aren't accessible on the site already, ask the vendors if they can supply drivers compiled for the Raspberry PI CPU arch you intend to use, otherwise you may need to write those based on a documented sdk they supply. Installing Android OS might be another option

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just wanted to know if anyone has use it before. If not can you suggest me what fingerprint scanner will be compatible with raspberry pi based on prior experience

Answer (score 0):

Yes the device is supported in raspberrypi as I have asked the manufacturer to provide the driver and they mailed me the driver